# How can I use a Django template tag for greater than on a forloop.counter?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want the effect of an "ifgt" template tag in a django template page:

```
{%ifgt forloop.counter 10%}<!---special greater than 10 code--!>{%endif%}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Django snippet will give you a smart if tag that you can use with operators such as greater than: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/

EDIT: Django now includes the smart if tag, so if you're on the latest version then you won't need that snippet.

Comment: Do you know if loading the "smart_if" template tags on a page will degrade the performance of normal "if" statements?

Comment: I can't imagine that it would be worse enough to cause any kind of noticeable difference.  I'd be incredibly shocked if there was so much as a 1 millisecond difference.

Answer (score 5):

If you **only** need *greater-than*, you can use the following easy snippet (put it into *app/templatetags/greaterthan.py*):

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def gt(a, b):
    return a > b
```

And in a template:

```
{% load greterthan %}
{% if forloop.counter|gt:10 %}...{% endif %}
```